# Catching async errors with context referenced to originating sync function

Tags: javascript

In the code below the error is never caught:

```js
const fn = () => {
  try {
    setTimeout(() => { throw new Error('An exception is raised') }, 10)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error({ error })
  }
}
fn()
```

The following is a solution:

```js
const fn2 = () => {
  const errorFn = (error) => console.error({ error })
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      throw new Error('An exception is raised')
    } catch (e) { errorFn(e) }
  }, 10)
}
fn2()
```

The downside to this solutions is that it has to be implement in the function within setTimeout.  That's fine if one controls the code, but if users are supplying the code and calling setTimeout and don't implement appropriate error handling, it could bring down one's server!

Another solution is `process.on('uncaughtException,...` but that loses the context of the originating sync call that initiated the async function.  Unless there is some clever way to supply that context?

Are there any other ways to catch async errors with context to the originating sync code?

Could one set a default error handler for a particular async branch - that catches all unhandled errors that may occur in that async branch?

Comment: Use promises, they provide proper error handling in `then` callbacks. Or go all the way to `async`/`await` syntax. But yes, never ever throw exceptions from an asynchronous callback.

Comment: @Bergi, if one uses a promise and then throws within `SetTimout` or `SetImmediate` the promise will not catch that error unless one does `reject(error)`.

Comment: I said not to throw in the asynchronous `setTimeout` callback. Fulfill the promise, do nothing else. Then do throw your exception (or call your buggy code) in a `then` callback chained to the promise.

Comment: "unless one does `reject(error)`." Yes. Then why don't you do `reject(error)` instead?

Comment: @Bergi, if I understand you, you are saying: no this cannot be done ...

Comment: @Ricky Mo `reject(error)` is the same as the solution I proposed in the question, but as I said, it requires users to implement their own error handling, and if they don't it could bring down the server.  Not a great solution at all!

Comment: I'm saying it *should* not be done. "*Are there any other ways to catch async errors with context?*" - there are [async hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) and there are [domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). But if your goal really is to run user-supplied code, exceptions are your smallest issue.

Comment: I don't understand your situation. Could you provide an example of "the user bringing down your server" ?

Comment: What did you mean by "if users are supplying the code" ? User should never supply the code. You have more trouble than catching an async error if  users can supply their code to run on your server.

Comment: @Ricky Mo on the server, users supply code that is run and results returned to the ui.  Their code should not be able to bring down the server and in particular if their code throws an unhandled error, I want to handle it and perhaps terminate their connection, but not bring down the server.  I could spawn a child process that they can then crash - but that's a big architectural decision.

Comment: @Ricky Mo think of it like ssh - ssh users supply code that is run on the server with results returned to the terminal.  An error should however not bring down the ssh server, it could perhaps terminate the individual ssh connection.

Comment: @TrevTheDev But it's an architectural decision you need to make. There are thousands of ways to bring down your server without throwing exceptions. If the goal even was to bring it down, and not just to install a bitcoin miner…

Comment: @Bergi thanks for  the `async_hooks` - I have been looking into that, but so far it doesn't look promising as I haven't found a way to inject a global error handler.

Comment: Do you mean you call `eval()` on user generated code, and that code happens to contain `setTimeout`, and the `setTimeout` block happen to throw error?

Comment: @Ricky Mo potentially yes.

Comment: @TrevTheDev `async_hooks` isn't doing error handling, but it lets you track context across asynchronous calls.

Comment: @Bergi, yes it does do that and one could keep a record of async calls but how would one link it to the information supplied by `process.on('uncaughtException,... ` ?